# Totally isotropic space for bilinear pairing over ring

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, modules, quadratic-forms, vector-spaces

A duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850381/totally-isotropic-subspace-for-bilinear-pairing-over-ring):

Consider the following well-known inequality: Let $b$
be a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear pairing over a (finite-dimensional) $\mathbb F$-vector space $V$ and $W$
a totally isotropic subspace. Then $\dim W \leq \dfrac{\dim V}{2}$.

I am trying to generalise a result for vector spaces to the case of modules over rings, and the proof of the former uses the above inequality to bound the dimension of a certain subspace, so I was wondering whether the analogous result exists for bilinear forms over rings (e.g. something bounding the length of a totally isotropic submodule in terms of the length of the ambient module). I don't have much experience with bilinear forms over rings, but the bibliography I found online does not mention a similar result.

It is possible that the notion of totally isotropic is substantially different over a ring due to the existence of zero-divisors, however I would be glad if someone could point out a related result (maybe dependent on some properties of the ring) or explain why such an inequality fails to hold over a ring.

Comment: Let's say you understand "non-degenerate" to mean that the canonical morphism $V \to V^*$ it induces is an isomorphism. Let's also say that $\mathbb F$ is a commutative ring, and that $V$ is a free $\mathbb F$-module, and that $W$ is a direct addend of $V$ as an $\mathbb F$-module. Then, you get a canonical embedding of $W$ into $V^* / W^*$, where $W^*$ is embedded into $V^*$ using the direct sum decomposition. Hence, $\operatorname{rank} W \leq \dfrac{\operatorname{rank} V}{2}$. But my assumptions may be far too restrictive for your tastes.

Comment: May be Proposition 3.7.1 (page 17) in Knus' "Quadratic and Hermitian Forms over Rings" is what you are looking for. In this case, the ambient $A$-module $M$ is a quadratic even hermitian space and $U\subseteq M$ is a totally isotropic direct summand of $M$.  Proposition 3.7.1  says that there is a submodule $V\subseteq M$ such that $M=U^{\perp}\oplus V$ and then use a length function on your $A$-modules. Here the ring $A$ is assumed to have an involution, which could be the trivial one.